# xorwf literal not affecting z flag even when literal value is same as value in w

Tags: microcontroller, microchip, assembly

According to Instruction Set Description
"xorwf myLiteral" should xor contents of "w" with "myLiteral" and if both are same then flag Z in STATUS must be set (not interested where this instruction saves the result but Z flag must be affected if both values were same)

But in my code this is not happening

```
movf PORTC
xorwf red_on    ;w holds 01000100 and red_on is also 01000100 Z must be one
btfsc STATUS, Z ;but here it's not one
goto Turn_Yellow_On
```

Full code is following:

```
    ; PIC16F72 Configuration Bit Settings

; Assembly source line config statements

#include "p16f72.inc"

; CONFIG
; __config 0xFFF7
 __CONFIG _FOSC_RC & _WDTE_ON & _PWRTE_ON & _CP_OFF & _BOREN_ON

STATUS equ 0x03
TRISC equ 0x87
PORTC equ 0x07
INTCON equ 0x0b

RP0 equ 5
RP1 equ 6
Z equ 2

GIE equ 7
INTE equ 4
INTF equ 1

all_off equ 0x00
red_on equ 0x44
yellow_on equ 0x22
green_on equ 0x11 

bank0 macro
    bcf STATUS, RP0
    bcf STATUS, RP1
    endm

bank1 macro
    bsf STATUS, RP0
    bcf STATUS, RP1
    endm

extrn_int_enable macro
    bsf INTCON, GIE
    bsf INTCON, INTE
    endm

PORTC_as_out macro
    bank1
    movlw 0x00
    movwf TRISC
    endm

PORTC_out macro outByte
    bank0
    movlw outByte
    movwf PORTC
    endm

test_and_switch macro testWith, jumpTo
    movf PORTC
    xorwf testWith
    btfsc STATUS, Z
    goto jumpTo
    endm

    org 0x00
Reset_Vector:
    goto Main

    org 0x04
Interrupt_Vector:
    goto Switch_Next

    org 0x05
Main:
    PORTC_as_out
    extrn_int_enable

Loop:
    clrwdt
    goto Loop

    org 0x200
Switch_Next:
    bcf INTCON, INTF

    ;test_and_switch all_off, Turn_Red_On
    movf PORTC      ;I recognized the mistake I should use d = 0 but data
    ;will still be copied in w when program goes to "Turn_Red_On" routine for 
    ;the first time
    xorwf all_off
    btfsc STATUS, Z
    goto Turn_Red_On

    ;test_and_switch red_on, Turn_Yellow_On
    movf PORTC
    xorwf red_on    ;w holds 01000100 and red_on is also 01000100 Z must be one
    btfsc STATUS, Z ;but here it's not one
    goto Turn_Yellow_On

    ;test_and_switch yellow_on, Turn_Green_On
    movf PORTC
    xorwf yellow_on
    btfsc STATUS, Z
    goto Turn_Green_On

    goto Turn_All_Off

Turn_Red_On:
    PORTC_out red_on
    goto Return_From_Int

Turn_Yellow_On:
    PORTC_out yellow_on
    goto Return_From_Int

Turn_Green_On:
    PORTC_out green_on
    goto Return_From_Int

Turn_All_Off:
    PORTC_out all_off
    goto Return_From_Int

Return_From_Int:
    retfie

    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your **movf PORTC** instruction lacks a destination.

The default is f, PORTC in this case, so you are not putting the number in the w register.

Change it to movf PORTC, w

And you should always state it explicitly to prevent problems. Running a simulation would probably have caught this, and it's worth learning how to do it.

Edit: 
Also, you are using **xorwf** (ex-or the w register with a file register), when you should be using **xorlw** (ex-or a literal with the w register).

**xorwf** takes the operand to be an **address** and xor's the w register with the contents of the register at that location (0x44, in the 96 bytes of general purpose registers), which is not what you want.

Comment: destination of the result is not point of interest atm. The undesired result is when w does hold 0x44 and xorwf 0x44 doesn't set Flag Z (it's astonishing to me). If you copy and simulate this code in MPLAB X and use stimulus to interrupt INT pin you'll notice on 2nd interrupt after entering Switch_Next label on about 7th line of code you'll notice the value of w would be 0x44 and "xorwf red_on" (red_on equ 0x44) still won't set Z in STATUS upon it's execution which is strange

Comment: See edit addition above.

Comment: Thanks it was my mistake I didn't recognize xorwf was taking literal as address not as constant value now I replaced it with xorlw and my code is working. Grateful to You!